# effective use of python shutil copy2

Tags: python, file, exception, copy, shutil

if we take a look at a file copy function, we can see there are several exceptions to handle. A good example is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx

my question is if i use python shutil copy2, what should I pay attention to cope with various exceptions (source file not found, access not authorized, etc.)?

e.g.

```
def copy_file (self):   
    if not os.path.isdir(dest_path):
        os.makedirs(dest_path)
    shutil.copy2(src_path, dest_path)
```

what should i do to the above function?

Comment: I don't think Python will throw C# exceptions, if that's your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may just need handle the `IOError` exception that may be caused due to any permissions or Invalid destination name issue.

```
try:
    shutil.copy(src,dst)
except IOError as e:
    print e
```

The other exceptions mentioned in the MSDN article seems to fall under the same IOError in python. The FileNotFound and DirectoryNotFound are not really applicable as shutil.copy will create the destination if it not already exists. Also, I find that happening of *OSError* are also remote this in case.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting checking only OSError. I'm not able to reproduce that shutil.copy will create destination directories nor does the documentation support that claim. I receive a IsADirectoryError or FileNotFoundError exception when shutil.copy'ing to a non-existent directory depending on if the destination filename is specified or not, respectively.